# Azure Diagnostics not working with Other build configuration

Tags: azure, system.diagnostics

I am working on an ASP.NET MVC web application which I am hosting as a Web App on Azure

I am following the steps as mentioned in the post by ScottGu [link](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/announcing-the-release-of-windows-azure-sdk-2-0-for-net) to enable tracing

But I am running into a strange problem, when I publish my app using the Visual Studio DEBUG build configuration on Azure tracing works, but when I use any other configuration (ex - TEST or RELEASE) it doesn't. I also compared the web.configs for the different configuration and they are identical..

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are having different behaviors in different configurations, it sounds to me like **Define** **TRACE** **constant** has been unchecked in your project's configuration under the **Build** tab.  Make sure it is checked in all your configurations.

Comment: Baam.. how could I miss that and never checked it :)... thanks it solved the issue